# Extract third letter from each line

Tags: bash

The following lines will execute the first command but I'm not sure how to cut the 3rd letter from the output

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EFO
Hello 
World 
How are you
EFO
&&
while read hello.sh 
 do  
  echo ${hello.sh} | cut -c3
 done
```

Expecting the below output:

```
l
r
w
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here, and it's not clear what exactly you need help with, especially since the syntax of this code is invalid and "execute the first string" doesn't really make sense. Are you looking for `cut -c3 << EFO`? Check out [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify if needed. And you'll probably want to pass your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) first and fix any problems it identifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and a useless `while read`. `cut` already knows how to read its own standard input.

```
cut -c3 <<EOF
Hello 
World 
How are you
EOF
```

The here document's delimiter can be any string really, but the conventional "EOF" stands for "end of file".

Also, you can't have dots in your variable names, and you should [wrap quotes around your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) unless you require the shell to perform whitespace splitting and wildcard expansion on the value. Finally, you want to use `read -r` unless you specifically want the legacy pre-POSIX behavior of `read` when it receives a backslash.

https://shellcheck.net/ can report and even fix many beginner problems like these; probably try it before asking for human assistance.

Syntactically, `a && b` means run `a` and check whether it succeeded; if it did, also run `b`. You seem to be looking for `a | b` which says "run `a` and `b`, with the standard output of `a` connected as `b`'s standard input".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple script that does what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EFO | while read -r input; do echo "${input:2:1}"; done
Hello
World
How are you
EFO
```

Comment: Avoid useless use of `cat`!: `while read ... done <<EFO`